# How can I get the Salesforce IAM to generate an OIDC compliant id_token on login?

Tags: identity, open-id-connect

We use Salesforce as our CRM.
However, there are aspects of our customer data that sits in external systems, that we need to use to augment the data presented on the CRM to our users.
We can access this data via APIs.

Our requirement (legal reasons) is to make calls to the API directly from the User-Agent (Salesforce Apex pages) and not via the Salesforce backend servers (Apex / Custom code).

To secure our APIs, we are exploring leveraging the existing Salesforce Identity and Access Management (IAM) and OpenID Connect (OIDC).

What we are seeking to do is

1. User logs in with 2FA
2. Once logged in successfully an OIDC compliant id_token is generated and sent to the User-Agent. The `id_token` has the same expiry as that of the Salesforce session. This can happen at the Salesforce server end - either via existing Salesforce services OR as custom code
3. When the user navigates to a Salesforce Apex page that needs to use the API, `javascript` on the Salesforce Apex page uses the `id_token` to call https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token endpoint and use the `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` token flow to retrieve an `access_token`
4. The User-Agent uses the `access_token` to call the API
5. The API uses its own credentials to `introspect` the `access_token` with https://login.salesforce.com
6. If the `access_token` is valid, then it will return back with data to the User-Agent
7. Data from the API is then used to update the previously rendered Salesforce Apex page

Is this possible?
If so, how can Salesforce be configured to enable this?

Currently struggling to get Salesforce to return an `id_token`.

Comment: Your question amounts to "How do I call a 3rd party API from Salesforce". The answer to this question depends on the 3rd party. Doing so from a front-end adds a wrinkle but ultimately this is not a Salesforce issue.

Comment: I agree, but only in part @identigral

The *issue* is around - how can I get Salesforce to dispense an OIDC standard compliant `id_token`. I can't seem to find any documentation around this.

There are lots of documentation for how Salesforce can *consume* tokens from other OIDC providers or Authorization Server - e.g use Google to login to salesforce - but not much on the reverse use-case. 

How can Salesforce act as the OIDC provider or Authorization Server, so a user can login to Salesforce - and that login be used to validate access to other apps/services?

Comment: The `login be used to validate access to other apps/services` can't be done for 3rd party APIs, intentionally. Out of the box, this is what you get: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_create_openid_connect.htm&type=5